# Realm Query Freezing App for large number of records

Tags: android, realm

I am running a realm query to retrieve a list of participants after which I am passing an individual participant as a parameter to a method, getCommunity(participant) to get the area in which the participant belongs.  I then go ahead and add all participants of a given community to a List so as to display them on a recycler view. Below is the code:

```
List<StoredParticipant> FilteredMembers = new ArrayList<>();
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        try {
            realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {
                RealmResults<StoredParticipant> participants = realm1.where(StoredParticipant.class).beginGroup()
                        .isNull("isDeceased")
                        .or()
                        .notEqualTo("isDeceased", true)
                        .endGroup().findAll();

                for (StoredParticipant storedParticipant : participants) {
                    String community = getCommunity(storedParticipant);
                    if (community.equalsIgnoreCase(Community)) {
                        FilteredMembers.add(storedParticipant);

                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

The line causing the lag is:
    String community = getCommunity(storedParticipant);

How should I rewrite the code to prevent the lag?

Edit: The code for getCommunity() is as below:

```
  public static String getCommunity(StoredParticipant participant) {
    String community = "";

    try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        HouseholdRelationship hhr = realm.where(HouseholdRelationship.class)
                .equalTo("participantId", participant.getId())
                .isNull("endDate")
                .findFirst();

        if (hhr != null) {
            Household household = realm.where(Household.class)
                    .equalTo("id", hhr.getHouseholdId())
                    .findFirst();

            if (household != null) {
                HouseholdAddress address = HouseholdService.getCurrentAddress(household);
                if (address != null) {
                    community = AreaService.getCommunityName(address.getArea());

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return community;
}
```

Comment: Why not also use `beginGroup()....endGroup().equalTo("community", Community)` instead of filtering in code?

Comment: "Community" field is not within StoredParticipant RealmList.  I have added the code for getCommunity()

Comment: Clearly, `community` should also be part of the `StoredParticipant`, possibly evaluated when the participant is stored.